# ERROR 1200: could not instantiate <UDF NAME> with arguments 'null'

Tags: java, apache-pig

I am trying to get Month Name (Jan-Dec) from timestamp in pig. I have written a UDF in Java (my first UDF) which looks like this :

```
package pig.data.preprocess;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class ColNameToTypeMap extends EvalFunc<String> {

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        Map<Integer, String> monthNamesMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        monthNamesMap.put(1, "Jan");
        monthNamesMap.put(2, "Feb");
        monthNamesMap.put(3, "Mar");
        monthNamesMap.put(4, "Apr");
        monthNamesMap.put(5, "May");
        monthNamesMap.put(6, "Jun");
        monthNamesMap.put(7, "Jul");
        monthNamesMap.put(8, "Aug");
        monthNamesMap.put(9, "Sep");
        monthNamesMap.put(10, "Oct");
        monthNamesMap.put(11, "Nov");
        monthNamesMap.put(12, "Dec");
        int monthId = (Integer)input.get(0);
        return monthNamesMap.get(monthId);
    }

}
```

And Following is the pig script which uses above UDF:

```
register '<path-to-jar>/month-name.jar';
DEFINE month_name pig.data.preprocess.ColNameToTypeMap();
month_n = FOREACH only_dates GENERATE id, month_name(GetMonth(ToDate(ts)));
DUMP month_n;
```

When I run this script it gives me following exception :

```
ERROR 1200: could not instantiate 'pig.data.preprocess.ColNameToTypeMap' with arguments 'null'

Failed to parse: could not instantiate 'pig.data.preprocess.ColNameToTypeMap' with arguments 'null'
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:201)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1707)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1680)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:623)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1082)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:505)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:565)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'pig.data.preprocess.ColNameToTypeMap' with arguments 'null'
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:772)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.getFieldSchema(UserFuncExpression.java:222)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.FieldSchemaResetter.execute(SchemaResetter.java:264)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.AllSameExpressionVisitor.visit(AllSameExpressionVisitor.java:143)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.accept(UserFuncExpression.java:113)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.walk(ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.java:70)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visitAll(SchemaResetter.java:67)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:122)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOGenerate.accept(LOGenerate.java:245)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:114)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildForeachOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1055)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.foreach_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:15896)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1933)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext can not access a member of class pig.data.preprocess.ColNameToTypeMap with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:110)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:377)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:742)
    ... 34 more
```

I have spent a lot of time but I could not figure-out the problem. Please help if someone has solved similar problem before.

Comment: what is  only_dates here? i dont see it is defined any where in pig script.

Answer (score 0):

When you are building the jar using ANT/Maven, all required libraries should be included in the jar. It seems, some libraries are missing.

Make sure that all dependencies are there.

Make sure you register the jar and declare all the variable like 'ts' in the script.